# Spreadsheet: formula to join rows

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to join some rows in a google spreadsheet document. The rows to join share the same value in the ID column. But the think is that the results have different columns.

Please, take a look a this live example to see what I mean: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fR7KTXa-XHtZW8hkUzM0Z--cQVj1KblHDRVY0711WH0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use a Pivot, although column labels will differ slightly from yours:

```
=query(A1:D,"select A,max(B),max(C) where A is not null group by A pivot D label max(B) 'Title',max(C) 'Description'",1)
```

[image]

If you had an extra column which had the same value across each ID, you could add it by pivoting on both (it would make no difference):

```
=query(A1:E,"select A,max(B),max(C),E where A is not null group by A,E pivot D label max(B) 'Title',max(C) 'Description'",1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this formula is easier to me to understand and modify-

Comment: Can you please help me a little more? I added the column E which is a value that I need NOT to PIVOT on the column D (lang). I just need to transpose these in a single (just one) column. The results should be the column L which I entered manually to show you what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, will add to my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will check on this later.

Comment: Hello Tom, can you help me with this? I you don't have the time for this, please just let me know and then I will open a new question for this.

Comment: Have pasted the 'no pivot value' it into your sheet as well

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ;unique(tocol(A2:A;1));Δ;index(torow(B1:C1&"-"&unique(tocol(D2:D;1));;1));
     {{A1;Σ}\{Δ;makearray(counta(Σ);counta(Δ);lambda(r;c;ifna(+filter(filter(B2:C;B1:C1=index(split(index(Δ;;c);"-");1));A2:A=index(Σ;r);D2:D=index(split(index(Δ;;c);"-");2)))))}})
```

[image]